# How to determine the literal meaning of the phrase 'instead of' in two related but independent conditional statements

Tags: grammar, possessives

Consider the following statements from an airline's terms and conditions:

> 1. If a flight is cancelled, you are entitled to a refund
> 2. If a flight is cancelled for external factors, you are entitled to a credit instead of a refund

Assuming the flight was indeed cancelled due to external factors, my understanding is that it is unclear whether the second clause **replaces** or **supplements** the first.

For example, the above statements could read that if a flight is cancelled for external factors, you are entitled to a credit **instead of being entitled to a refund**. In this case, there is no choice to receive a refund. I assume this is what the airline intended when it wrote statement 2. This would be the common sense answer.

However, the reason I pose this question is because hypothetically it seems statement 1 and 2 could be read differently - that if a flight is cancelled, you are entitled to a [refund], as per condition 1, and if a flight is cancelled for external factors, you are entitled to the option of a [credit instead of the previously-entitled refund], i.e. change the refund to a credit, as per condition 2. This would imply that the flight being cancelled for external factors provides you with an **additional** entitlement of flexibility (i.e. the option to change the previous refund entitlement to a credit).

So in both scenarios you get the refund from the first condition, but then receive additional flexibility to change said refund to a credit from the second condition.

My current understanding is that it is unclear whether the 'instead of' applies to the **object** of the entitlement (credit/refund), or the **entitlement itself**.

I would therefore like to better understand whether the above statements from the airline's terms and conditions provide the ambiguous possibility of a refund if a flight is cancelled due to external factors, or if the statements are as 100% conclusive and unambiguous as the airline seems to believe.

**Disclaimer:** Although this is a real-world example, I'm not asking for legal advice, nor am I majorly concerned with the outcome (i.e whether I receive a credit or refund). I am asking this question out of curiosity, since it got me thinking, and reminded me of an interesting legal case regarding an oxford comma: [https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/09/us/oxford-comma-maine.html][1]. Apologies if I'm being pedantic and if this is not a suitable question for this forum. To me it seems like the ambiguity is very obvious, and while I understand my argument is extremely pedantic and not very 'common sensey', it seems no different to that of the Oxford Comma example, which is also very pedantic and not very 'common sensey'. I appreciate I may not have communicated my point elegantly, so apologies in advance for any confusion.
[1]: https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/09/us/oxford-comma-maine.html

Comment: _Instead of_ normally means that one thing replaces another, doesn't it?

Comment: @KateBunting But in this example, what is being replaced? It could be read that the second phrase replaces the first (i.e. the new entitlement to a pear replaces the previous entitlement to an apple, leaving you with only an entitlement to a pear), but it could also be read that the second phrase provides an additional entitlement, with the replacement happening should you choose a pear (in which case, the pear would replace the apple). In the first example, you have only one choice (pear), but in the second example, you have two choices (pear or apple).

Comment: It's ambiguous as far as I can tell. You only get one fruit, but it's not clear if the second statement invalidates or supplements the first - context might make it clearer. If this is a real-world case, speak to your fruit distributor. If you're writing entitlements, specify more clearly.

Comment: If you are presented with 2 rules together like this, adjacent in the same document, then it probably means both apply and you get either fruit. But if someone sends you rule 1 and later rule 2, it may be that rule 2 replaces rule 1 (pear only), or that rule 1 still applies (either fruit).

Comment: @StuartF Would adding a comma after 'pear' remove the ambiguity? Or if rule 2 was intended to replace rule 1, would the only way to remove ambiguity be to re-write the sentence explicity, for example 'you are entitled to a pear, and are no longer entitled to an apple'?

Comment: @StuartF The real-world example is a flight I booked, which was cancelled by the airline. In the airline's terms and conditions, it states that if a flight is cancelled, I am entitled to a refund. However it also states (in the same document), that if a flight is cancelled due to external factors (which is the case), then I am "entitled to a credit instead of a refund". I would prefer a refund, which the airline are refusing due to the above phrase. My argument is that this exclusion is ambiguous, and could reasonably be read that the second clause supplements rather than replaces the first.

Comment: @Alan Thank you for stating the real-life situation. This shows us something which your fruit example didn't. The preconditions of the two respective entitlements are different. If the airline cancels the flight, it entitles you to a refund. However, if it cancels it because of external factors, then you are entitled to a credit instead of a refund, and so you are not entitled to a refund. There were external factors, so the second rule countermands the first.

Comment: @RosieF Are you sure this means the second rule countermands the first? Doesn't the first rule still apply, since the flight was cancelled? I could re-write the fruit example as: 1) You are entitled to an apple, 2) If X is true, you are entitled to an pear instead of a apple, 3) X is true. However is this not still ambiguous, since it is unclear whether the 'instead of' refers to the objects (apple/pear), or the entitlement? In the flight example, since condition 1 was true, I entitled to a [refund], and since condition 2 is true, I am **also** entitled to a [credit instead of a refund], no?

Comment: @RosieF My understanding is that condition 1 applies (flight cancelled for any reason), which entitles me to a [refund]. Condition 2 also applies (flight cancelled for external factors), which entitles me to a [credit instead of a refund]. So when conditions 1 and 2 are both true, I am entitlement to a [refund], and also a [credit instead of a refund]. Since condition 1 still applies, I would read it that condition 2 gives me the **additional option** of a credit instead a refund.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I've updated my original question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for the suggestion, title is now updated and previous example removed.

Comment: Applying a simple dollop of common sense enables us to understand that 2. replaces 1. if a flight is cancelled for external factors.

Comment: It's worth noting that the legal interpretation of either phrase may not be same as the plain English interpretation,  depending on who writes the contract, legal precedence, and a myriad of other factors.

Comment: @BillJ I agree, however specifically I am asking if this also applies in a **literal** sense. For example in the Oxford Comma example I linked in the question, the common sense interpretation was very different to the literal interpretation, and the real-world implication of such a difference was non-trivial. Hence I was wondering if there is technically a right or wrong answer here.

Comment: As BillJ says, everyday English works by using pragmatics (normal readings of phraseology) to disambiguate, as well as strictly logical interpretations. But it is a stipulation on ELU that legal usages of language (which are known to differ, on occasion, from everyday usages) may not be solicited. I'm afraid only the legal profession will resolve your problem.

Comment: I would have thought that, if it was intended as an alternative, they would have specified _You **may choose** to accept B instead of A_.

Comment: Lots of useful perspectives which is great. On reflection my current understanding is that 1) although in isolation, the statements seem to provide ambiguous logic if read literally, 2) literal plain English interpretation can be very different to common sense interpretation, which can be very different to legal interpretation, 3) only after understanding a myriad of external factors is it possible to ultimately determine which interpretation method takes precedence, and 4) it is now clear why legal contracts can be subjective and why some legal cases drag out for years.